# Backgroundworker progresbar marquee while busy?

Tags: vb.net

So im pretty sure its simple enough but im trying to start the marqee progress bar style, run a function, than stop it when complete..

Ive got my background workers;

make_progress (changed progress)
make_complete (worker complete)
make_dowork (where im calling the function)
makebuttonm (the button click sender to make_dowork)
makefunction (core of my code)

I have tried putting the make_progress.reportprogress(x) into the function, also tried calling the style to change on the button (before the do_work process is called) and none of them start the marquee but the UI is free, and I see the files created..

The hard part is that I dont have a  way to seeing "progress" because im waiting for an external command to complete... and using a consoleredirect ends up just freezing my UI

any suggestions on where to call the start ? (the end is easy in the workcomplete) and I have my handlers in the right places

```
Function MakeAppx()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim ProgDir As String = "C:\"
    Dim listofapp As List(Of String) = FileHelper.GetFilesRecursive(ProgDir)
    Dim FoundApp As New List(Of String)
    Dim AppPath As String
    PackappComplete = False

    'Find Each Instance of the makeappx.exe file, gets absolute path for us
    For Each I In listofapp
        If I.Contains("x) Then
            AppPath = I
            make.StartInfo.FileName = (AppPath)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim Per As Integer
    Per = Per + 1

    make.StartInfo.Arguments = psi
    make.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    make.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    make.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    make.Start()

End Function
Private Sub bw_make(ByVal Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles packapp.DoWork
    packapp.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    AddHandler packapp.ProgressChanged, AddressOf packapp_change
    AddHandler packapp.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf packapp_complete
    Sender = MakeAppx()

End Sub
Private Sub packapp_change(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles packapp.ProgressChanged
    copyprogress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
End Sub
Private Sub packapp_complete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted



End Sub
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    AddHandler packapp.ProgressChanged, AddressOf packapp_change
    AddHandler packapp.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf packapp_complete
    OrigionalAppLoc = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(LocalApps).ToList

    copyprogress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee

    For Each I In OrigionalAppLoc
        If I.Contains(Trim(lbGetApps.SelectedItem)) Then
            apppath = I
        End If
    Next
    psi = (" pack /l /d """ & Trim(apppath) & """ /p ""C:\Apps\" & Trim(lbGetApps.SelectedItem) & ".appx""")
    packapp.RunWorkerAsync(sender)

End Sub
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Metr... err... Windows 8 Modern Store-style app?

Comment: sorry, missed the paste